# Azure Function EventHub Output Binding

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm starting to develop an Azure Function that sends messages to an Event Hub.

Using the example provided on [Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=csharp#example) I'm able to send an event using the return value of the HTTP trigger.

```
[FunctionName("EventHubOutput")]
[return: EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
public static string Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
  log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
  return $"{DateTime.Now}";
}
```

For my implementation, I don't want to use the return value of the function trigger (in my case HTTP) and would like to use the output of a method within the function. The reason for this is that I would like to validate the request method and only send the message to the event hub is it passes validation.

I can replace **return:** with **method:** but I can't find any documentation which tells me how to implement **method:**.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want to accomplish, if you want to use the output of a method, wouldn't it be enough to call the method within the function and return its value?

Comment: What I’m trying to accomplish is a HTTP trigger function which returns a HTTP status only. Within the function I want to validate the received request payload. If it passes validation, the payload will be sent to the Event Hub and the trigger returns a success status. If it fails validation the message is not sent to the Event Hub and the function returns an error status. 
At the moment, the return: is the return value for the HTTP trigger which will Always send a message to the Event Hub and I don’t want that. I want to return the output from the validation method.

Comment: Then do you really need the output binding? Maybe remove that binding and just send the message to the EventHub with the EventHubClient, kind of what this example does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

Comment: As devcrp says, we can use EventHubClient to send message to eventhub directly. It is as same as output binding.

Comment: If you dont have more doubts, can we end this question now?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use output binding, you can use code to send directly, they are the same principle. Code about how to send a message to the event hub:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#write-code-to-send-messages-to-the-event-hub

Comment: That link is pointing to guidance for the legacy version of Event Hubs; you'd probably want to use the current version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2#send-events

Comment: While this does not answer the original question, it will give me what I need and I already have some working code that uses this method, so accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following into your header for your Azure Function:

```
[EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]IAsyncCollector<[your type here]> eventsToSend
```

You can now use the following to queue messages for transmission in a threadsafe manner (i.e. it works just fine if you have a series of threads queuing to it at the same time):

```
await eventsToSend.AddAsync([Your Object]).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If you have nothing to send out, you do not call the .AddAsync() method in your code.